# Displaying buttons with programmatic constraints

Tags: swift, uiview, uibutton, xcode8, ios10

Despite adding constraints on leading and top anchors for my buttons (I am trying to display them in a list), the view displays all of them in the top left corner of the view. I am calling many methods to try to apply the constraints, but none of them seem to be working. Help!

```
func displayButtonArray(buttons: [UIButton]) {
    var previousButton: UIButton = buttons[0]
    for (i, button) in buttons.enumerated() {
        button.setTitle("SampleButton", for: .normal)
        button.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
        button.sizeToFit()

        let margins = self.view.layoutMarginsGuide
        button.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.leadingAnchor)
        if i == 1 {
            button.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.topAnchor, constant: CGFloat(5.0))
        } else {
            button.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: previousButton.bottomAnchor, constant: CGFloat(10.0))
        }
        previousButton = button

        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        button.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()
        button.setNeedsLayout()

        self.view.addSubview(button)
    }
    self.view.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()
    self.view.setNeedsLayout()
    self.view.layoutSubviews()
}
```

Comment: Found my problem, I need to set .isActive = true for the constraints I made. I assumed the functions would have the side-effects when instead they create the constraints that if isActive is set to true, then it would have side-effects

Answer (score 0):

As you pointed out as well, constraints are defined but not activated.

One thing I can add is that as it's mentioned by Apple, AutoLayout constraints should be activated all together.

You may activate them one by one but it's more efficient to activate them all together; leading to better performance.